# Why complex integral along unit circle centered at origin of $\frac{1}{z}$ is different compared to $\frac{1}{z^2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

What I am looking for is a geometrical, or rather intuitive, explanation of why a complex integral of $1/z$ along the unit circle centred at the origin is different from that of $1/z^2$. I understand technical stuff regarding the integral, meaning that I can prove

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int \frac{dz}{z^m}=\begin{cases} 1  & m=1 \\
0 & m\ne1
\end{cases}$$

Comment: $z^{-2}$ has an antiderivative, $z^{-1}$ doesn't.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think that you ought to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @José, I think OP should digest my comment, and post an elaboration as an answer. But, thanks.

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson I understand that. Also $z^{-1}$ has antiderivative $logz$ which has branch cut where as $z^{-1}$ doesn't have branch cut.

Comment: @RahulRajuPattar No. $z^{-1}$ has *no* antiderivative in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @ José Carlos Santos, $z^{-1}$  does have antiderivative in unit disk minus the interval [0,1]

Comment: For sure and this is one branch of log. But the unit circle crosses exactly one branch cut, where we have an difference of $2\pi i$ in the argument.

Comment: My geometrical intuition for this is as follows. As you know, an integral can be thought of intuitively as a sum of "infinitesimally small" elements. In the complex plane, you can imagine these elements as 2D vectors or arrows of infinitesimal length; summing then just means putting the arrows one after another. See e.g. [this animation](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Path_integral_example.webm) for an illustration of this; you should replace the bottom image in your head with a point traveling along the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: As one travels along the circle, the arrows rotate at a speed determined by the $z^{-m}$ and $dz$. Concretely, the $z^{-m}$ contributes a speed of $m$ units clockwise (if $m$ is positive), while $dz$ contributes a speed of $1$ counterclockwise. This can be made explicit with a change of variables $z^{-m} = e^{-im\phi}$, $dz=i e^{i\phi} d\phi$. Now, when the speed is nonzero, the arrows end up closing in a circle, so their sum is zero. But when the speed is zero (when $m=1$), the arrows don't rotate, so placing one after another results in a straight line, and the integral is nonzero

Comment: What is the intuitive explanation of  $1$ being different from $2$?